# Using OR in a Scope Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Agency` model that has attributes: `from_age` and `to_age`, both are ints.  My goal is to be able to find all agencies within a certain age range.

**Note**: The stored value: 1000 represents the concept "and up".  This value is stored within `to_age` so that ranges can be specified like so:

- Serves Ages 18 `and up` (from_age = 18 while to_age = 1000)
- Serves Ages 21 `and up` (from_age = 21 while to_age = 1000)

And when both `from_age` and `to_age` have normal values:

- Serves Ages 25 - 40 (from_age = 25 while to_age = 40)
- Serves Ages 19 - 24 (from_age = 19 while to_age = 24)

So I am trying to write a scope to grab all agencies within this age range.  I don't think the scope I have is working as expected:

```
#modeles/agency.rb
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between_19_24, ->{where("from_age >= ? AND to_age <= ? OR to_age = ?", 19, 24, 1000)}
  ...
end
```

So with this query I am trying to grab two sets

- Grab all the agencies where `from_age` >= 19 AND `to_age` <= 24
- Grab all the agencies where `from_age` >= 19 AND `to_age` = 1000 (1000 represents the concept of "and up"

In the rails console when I do `agencies = Agency.between_19_24` it runs this query:

```
SELECT `agencies`.* FROM `agencies`  WHERE (from_age >= 19 AND to_age <= 24 OR to_age = 1000)
```

I don't think I have this right because that `or` statement should be something like this, where the OR is specified only for the last part:

```
# I added parenthesis to the part where the or statement should apply
SELECT `agencies`.* FROM `agencies`  WHERE (from_age >= 19 AND (to_age <= 24 OR to_age = 1000))
```

**Update**

My solution after reviewing all the help:

```
scope :age_between, -> (lower, upper){ where("(from_age <= ? AND to_age >= ?) OR to_age = ?", lower, upper, -1)}
```

`-1` stands for the concept of "Serves all Ages.  So this is saying: "Grab all the agencies that, at a minimum, serve the desired age range.  If an agency doesn't meet that criteria: grab any of those agencies that serve all ages.

Comment: What stops you from adding the parenthesis to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it easier to seperate the scopes?

```
scope :older_then, -> (age=18) { where('agencies.from_age > ?' age)) }
scope :younger_then, -> (age=65) { where('agencies.from_age < ?' age)) }

18+ Agency.all.older_then(18)
18-50 18+ Agency.all.older_then(18).younger_then(50)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you almost solved the problem - just some brackets are missing:

```
scope :between_19_24, -> {
  where('from_age >= ? AND (to_age <= ? OR to_age = ?)', 19, 24, 1000)
}
```

Or more general:

```
scope :serves, ->(range) {
  where('from_age >= ? AND (to_age <= ? OR to_age = 1000)', range.min, range.max)
}

# can be used like:
Agency.serves(19..24)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to achieve the result you want.

```
class Agency < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :between_19_24, ->{where("from_age >= ? AND (to_age <= ? OR to_age = ?)", 19, 24, 1000)}
 end
```